# Nest php Variable in href

Tags: php, href, kirby

I use Kirby as my CMS and i am trying to use a Variable to insert a Link at a icon. But it doesn't work. I tried out 2 ways. 
First this:

```
<a href='<?= $page->team01_member_fb()->html() ?>' target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/facebook_ico.svg"></a>
```

Than this one:

```
<?php echo '<a href=" '.$page->team01_member_Test()->html().' ">Link text</a>'; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now i know what was the Problem.

I had an foreach Loop, because the Element i filled with my Variables was repeated so many times like i added itself.

So i needed to change the normal Variable Call to an array-Variable call like below:

```
<a href='<?= $section['team01_member_fb'] ?>' target="_blank"><img src="assets/images/facebook_ico.svg"></a>
```

Hope this Helps someone!

Comment: glad you fixed it :)